# Using a DisplayPort to VGA adapter downscales resolution?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have a GTX 1060 Zotac, that only supports HDMI, DisplayPort, and DVI-D. I have a HDMI monitor hooked up, then another that only supports VGA. To hook up the VGA monitor, I got a DisplayPort to VGA adapter. Everything displays on both monitors, but the second one can only go up to 720p (It's a 1080p monitor) I've re-installed the drivers. I tried setting a custom resolution in Nvidia control panel, but it seems wrong. Everything isn't scaled correctly. The monitor in question in an AOC i2269VW.

Comment: "Video Graphics Array (VGA) refers specifically to the display hardware first introduced with the IBM PS/2 line of computers in 1987" There is probably nothing wrong.  Welcome to 1987.  If you have already tried messing with the resolution in windows, then your next best option it to just get monitor with a better selection of ports.

Comment: @MusselmanLLC  The VGA Supports 1080p60fps. My old graphics card was able to transfer 1080p60fps on the same monitor I'm using now, with VGA.

Comment: Well if your drivers are up to date, and there are no adjustments to the monitor or in Windows that can be made.  I would suspect that the adapter is causing some issue.  The adapter might be designed for a 720 signal.